# Compaing datetimes, does "less than" mean "longer ago"

Tags: apex

I have searched around but google cannot quite understand what I am asking. It seems simple but I can't seem to nail it down in my head, I'm probably thinking about it too hard. I am comparing two datetimes:

```
if(datetimeX < datetimeY)
```

... if this is true would that mean that from the present moment datetimeX is farther in the past than datetimeY ? Or, if this is true, has a greater amount of time elapsed since the exact moment of datetimeY which though the if is true would acutally mean datetimeY is farther in the past ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us take time to be linear...

In all seriousness, thinking of it not as past or future but as points on a timeline (regardless of the location on that timeline of `DateTime.now()`) helps. The infinitely far left end of the timeline is the beginning of the universe, and time proceeds to the right.

```
datetimeA < dateTimeB
```

evaluates to `true` when `datetimeA` is earlier (further left) on the timeline than `datetimeB`. Note, though, that both datetimes could just as well be in the future: `2018-12-31 < 2019-01-01`.